# How to arrange the flow of reactive values in R Shiny in a manner that avoids circular dependencies?

Tags: r, shiny, circular-dependency, observers, rhandsontable

The R Shiny code posted at the bottom allows the user to add columns to a `rhandsontable` table, allows manual inputs into the first row of the table, and automatically populates the non-editable second row of the table with reactive values from the linked dataframe called `table2`. The left-half of the below image shows how the App works.

As I point out in the right-half of the image below, there appears to be a circular dependency in passing the reactive `table2` object between observers. Any ideas for how to eliminate this circular dependency?

I thought combining those two observers into a single observer, and then passing the `tmpTable` object between functions in that same combined observer might work, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

You'll notice that sometimes when running this code and adding a column (if you add a column, change the "Month" value in the rendered `rhandsontable` table, and then directly click "Add" again), the rendered `rhandsontable` starts flashing and locks up, due to the circular dependency of that `table2` object I believe. Oddly, if you add a column, change the "Month" value, and click on a table cell before clicking "Add" again, this flashing/freeze doesn't happen. Circular dependency.

Illustrations:

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

mydata <- data.frame('Col1' = c(1,1), row.names = c('Month','END'))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("dft","DFT",min=0.1,max=1,value=0.3,step=0.1),
  tableOutput("table1"),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable'),
  actionButton("addCol","Add")
)

server <- server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dft_vector <- reactive(rep(input$dft,5))
  table2 <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  runOff <- reactive({
    f      <- function(x,y){x*(1-dft_vector()[y]/12)}
    res    <- Reduce(f,seq(5),init=250,accumulate=TRUE)
    b      <- head(res,-1)
    result <- data.frame(MO=seq(5),DFT=b*dft_vector()/12,END=res[-1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable,{table2(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  observe({
    req(runOff(), table2())
    tmpTable <- table2()
    tmpTable[2,] <- runOff()$END[unlist(table2()[1,])]
    table2(tmpTable)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addCol, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1)) 
    names(newCol) <- paste0("Col",ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable))+1)
    table2(cbind(table2(),newCol))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable(runOff())
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(table2(),useTypes=TRUE) %>% hot_row(c(2),readOnly=TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Same here - I can't reproduce the issue.